# Number of different hypergraphs realizable on N vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I am interested in the following: Given $N$ vertices, how many different hypergraphs in total can be realized on them counting the equivalent hypergraphs only once. Consider two hypergraphs equivalent if one can be transformed into another just by relabeling the vertices (for example $\{1,2\},\{2,3\}$ on 3 vertices is equivalent to $\{2,3\},\{1,3\}$). 
I am not really familiar with the graph theory terminology, but this question can probably be rephrased like this: What is the number of different hypergraphs relizable on $N$ unlabeled vertices.

By exhaustion, i have found:

1) N=1 only 1 Hg

2) N=2 only 2 Hg-s

3) N=3, 5 Hg-s

4) N=4, 20 Hg-s

but these numbers might not be correct!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this problem we basically require  the cycle index of the induced
action of the  symmetric group $S_N$ on the powerset  of the vertices.
This  can  be  done  by  constructing  representatives  of  the  cycle
structures from $Z(S_N)$, applying them to the powersets and factoring
the result,  making use of  the fact that the order of the  subsets is
constant on the orbit so we do  not have to allocate them all at once,
iterating  over the  subset size  instead.   Add to  obtain the  cycle
index.  We can then count hypergraphs by setting all variables to $2.$
This will yield

$$2, 4, 12, 80, 3984, 37333248, 25626412338274304, 
\\ 67516342973185974328175690087661568, \ldots$$

We also obtain the corresponding cycle indices e.g. for seven vertices
we find

$$\frac{1}{5040}
\left({a_{{1}}}^{128}+21\,{a_{{1}}}^{64}{a_{{2}}}^{32}
+105\,{a_{{1}}}^{32}{a_{{2}}}^{48}+105\,{a_{{1}}}^{16}{a_{{2}}}^{56}
+70\,{a_{{1}}}^{32}{a_{{3}}}^{32}
\\ +420\,{a_{{1}}}^{16}{a_{{2}}}^{8}{a_{{3}}}^{16}{a_{{6}}}^{8}
+210\,{a_{{1}}}^{16}{a_{{2}}}^{8}{a_{{4}}}^{24}
+280\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{3}}}^{40}
+630\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{12}{a_{{4}}}^{24}
\\ +210\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{12}{a_{{3}}}^{8}{a_{{6}}}^{12}
+504\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{5}}}^{24}
+840\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{4}{a_{{6}}}^{18}
\\ +420\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{4}
{a_{{4}}}^{6}{a_{{6}}}^{2}{a_{{12}}}^{6}
+504\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{5}}}^{12}{a_{{10}}}^{6}
+720\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{7}}}^{18}\right).$$

Armed  with  these  data  we  discover  that  the  sequence  is  [OEIS
A003180](https://oeis.org/A003180)  and  that  the  problem  has  been
investigated by several  authors. Among more recent work  there is the
paper *Enumeration of  hypergraphs* by Toru Ishihara  in the *European
Journal of Combinatorics*,  Volume 22, Issue 4, May  2001. We discover
on  consulting this  work  that  the results  obtained  therein are  a
perfect  match of  what we  have above.   The author  also adopts  the
convention of including  the empty set among the  hyperedges, a choice
that       we        make       as       well.         Note       that
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph)             says
different. The algorithm proposed by the paper is simple and efficient
and not at all difficult to implement, consult the Maple program shown
below, which  makes it possible  to compute  e.g. the cycle  index for
hypergraphs on $25$ vertices, here is an excerpt:

$$\cdots+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{16384}{a_{{2}}}^{57344}
{a_{{3}}}^{16384}{a_{{6}}}^{319488}
{a_{{5}}}^{49152}{a_{{10}}}^{172032}{a_{{15}}}^{49152}{a_
{{30}}}^{958464}}{870912000}}
\\ +{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{64}{a_{{2}}}^{224}
{a_{{4}}}^{384}{a_{{8}}}^{3840}{a_{{3}}}^{1344}{a_{{6}}}^{86624}{a_
{{12}}}^{130944}{a_{{24}}}^{1309440}}{3456}}
\\ +{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{64}
{a_{{3}}}^{320}{a_{{9}}}^{465920}{a_{{2}}}^{32}{a_{{6}}}^{160}{a_{{
18}}}^{232960}{a_{{4}}}^{96}{a_{{12}}}^{480}{a_{{36}}}^{698880}}{
3888}}
\\ +{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{128}{a_{{5}}}^{6528}{a_{{2}}}^{960}{a_{{
10}}}^{835392}{a_{{3}}}^{128}{a_{{6}}}^{960}{a_{{15}}}^{6528}{a_{{
30}}}^{835392}}{7200}}
\\ +{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8192}{a_{{2}}}^{12288}{a_
{{4}}}^{122880}{a_{{8}}}^{983040}{a_{{3}}}^{8192}{a_{{6}}}^{12288}{
a_{{12}}}^{122880}{a_{{24}}}^{983040}}{348364800}}+\cdots$$

This is the code.

```
with(combinat); with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

TI_mu :=
proc(pv)
local p, n, beta, ind, res;

    if pv = 1 then return 2 fi;

    p := op(2, ifactors(pv));
    n := nops(p);

    res := 0;

    for ind from 2^n to 2^(n+1)-1 do
        beta := convert(ind, base, 2);

        res := res +
        (-1)^add(beta[q], q=1..n)
        *2^mul(p[q][1]^(p[q][2]-beta[q]),
               q=1..n);
    od;

    res/pv;
end;

TI_rcyc :=  r -> mul(a[p]^TI_mu(p), p in divisors(r));

CART_prod :=
proc(t1, t2)
local v1, v2, l1, l2, res;

    res := 1;

    for v1 in indets(t1) do
        l1 := op(1, v1);
        for v2 in indets(t2) do
            l2 := op(1, v2);

            res := res *
            a[lcm(l1, l2)]^
            (gcd(l1, l2)
             *degree(t1, v1)
             *degree(t2, v2));
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

CART_pow :=
proc(t, q)
local res, p;

    res := t;

    for p to q-1 do
        res := CART_prod(res, t);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_hypergraph :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local term, v, contr, edgidx, edgterm;

    if n = 0 then return a[1] fi;
    if n = 1 then return a[1]^2 fi;

    edgidx := 0;

    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        edgterm := 1;

        for v in indets(term) do
            contr :=
            CART_pow(TI_rcyc(op(1, v)),
                     degree(term, v));

            if type(edgterm, `integer`) then
                edgterm := contr;
            else
                edgterm :=
                CART_prod(edgterm, contr);
            fi;
        od;

        edgidx :=
        edgidx + lcoeff(term) * edgterm;
    od;

    edgidx;
end;

hypergraph :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx, vars;

    idx := pet_cycleind_hypergraph(n);
    vars := indets(idx);

    subs([seq(v=2, v in vars)], idx);
end;
```