# Number of different connected hypergraphs with hyperedges covering exactly 3 vertices realizable on N total vertices

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, hypergraphs

I am interested in the following: Given N vertices, how many different(up to graph-isomorphism) hypergraphs with every hyperedge covering exactly 3 different vertices, every vertex gets covered at least once and the hypergraph is connected exist?

For N <= 2: 0  because not enough vertices

N=3: 1  just {1,2,3} with numbers representing vertices and the set of numbers representing the hyperedge

N=4: 3  this {{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}} that {{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {1,3,4}} and {{1,2,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,3,4}}

N=5: more than 8

This question is quite similar to the following-only that I am a bit more restrictive.
[Number of different hypergraphs realizable on N vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732440/number-of-different-hypergraphs-realizable-on-n-vertices)

I hope the question is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use mathjax for all math symbols. Other than that, I think this is a nice question and I’ll give it some thought.